# Get variable address using inline assembly

Tags: c++, windows, variables, assembly

I want a code to get the address of a variable using inline assembly with C++.

I'm doing this way, but it takes a value and not the address

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    DWORD addr;

   __asm mov ebx, n;
   __asm mov addr, ebx;

    printf("%x", addr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want make it with inline assembly, not c++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to do it via assembler, try

```
__asm lea ebx, n;
__asm mov addr, ebx;
```

Comment: just that! Thank you!

Comment: @user3448245 Note that this is correct for local variables, but not for static variabes.

Comment: @EJP Could you please provide corresponding link/reference?